# How to display a message by clicking a link in php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, function, fatal-error

How to display the message by clicking the subject(subject is a link)..
These are the lines to retrieve the data from database

```
echo "<td width='180px' align='left'>"."<a href='#' onclick='loadmessage()'>".$row1['subject']."</a>"."</td>";?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function loadmessage()
    {
        <?php 
        echo "hi";
        echo "<td align='left'>"."<textarea name='msg_content' cols='120' rows='2' readonly>".$row1['msg']."</textarea>"."</td>";?>
    }                   
</script>
 <?php
```

This code says "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare loadmessage() (previously declared in F:\wamp\www\sample\inbox.php:132) in F:\wamp\www\sample\inbox.php on line 132"..
Thank You...

Comment: change the name of loadmessage function

Comment: the `onclick` attribute refers to a *javascript* function, NOT a php function.

Comment: first and second comments are great, lol

Comment: @OZ_ was going to comment the same thing haha

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that your `loadmessage()` is a php function and you are calling that from javascript.

Comment: @Akam then how to call the function...

Comment: @AndRaGhu Can you maybe show a little more on what you like to accomplish? you like to display a new cell when someone presses the subject?

Comment: @Akam ya that's what i want now..

Comment: I changed the code, but it doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the function as follows, put it into myutils.inc.php and use require_once("myutils.inc.php"); to whereever you want to use this function.

and call it like loadMessage($row1['msg']);

```
function loadmessage($message)
{
   echo "hi";
   echo "<td align='left'>"."<textarea name='msg_content' cols='120' rows='2' readonly>".$message."</textarea>"."</td>";
}
```

This way, you can solve your fatal error.
However, @Mr. Alien is right that if you want to show this message on an instant-click, you have to use javascript for that.

Add your html to the code but leave it's content as empty.(infact, this is a must if you are using a table; because not adding the necessary  elements will break the table. Add an id to this td like this:

```
<td id="<?php echo 'rowid_'.$row1['id'];?>" ....>
<a href="javascript:showMessage(<?php echo $row1['msg'];?>,<?php echo 'rowid_'.$row1['id'];?>">click me</a></td>




  <script language="javascript">
function showMessage(msg,field){
document.getElementById(field).InnerHTML=msg;
}
    </script>
```

Comment: why down vote? this is the full answer. You really discourage people who want to answer.

Comment: oh sorry i am not doing like that..

Answer (score 3):

Oh you really need to understand the difference between client side and server side programming, you cannot invoke JavaScript through PHP

Instead use this

```
<script>
function loadmessage() {
   alert('blahblah');
}
</script>
```

Comment: K. But before this i tried that to.

Comment: @AndRaGhu with the script tags?

Comment: Alienyes within the script tags..

Comment: @AndRaGhu Than it should alert, no way it wont work

Answer (score 2):

PHP is serversided, you can't onclick a php function, you should use Javascript or jQuery for that. Try this:

Answer (score 2):

php code

```
echo "<td width='180px' align='left'>"."<a href='#' onclick='loadmessage()'>".$row1['subject']."</a>"."</td>";
```

// Javascript code

```
<script>
    function loadmessage() {
     alert('hi')
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

### 1. for simple message alert

**php code**

`echo "<a onclick=\"return alert('hello');\">helloo</a>";`

### 2 and call the value of variable in message box..

php code

`$d = "Hello how r u";` // using assign varable.

`echo "<a onclick=\"return alert('$d');\">helloo</a>";` //call the value of variable in alert box

Hope its use full for you....